# Вырезание одного полигона из другого

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика

У меня есть некий набор точек. Которые представляют из себя полигон P1-8. И есть другой полигон L1-4. Я не могу найти способ/алгоритм, с которым я смогу вырезать квадрат из полигона, и на выходе получить новый набор точек(координат естественно). На всякий случай укажу, что всё действо происходит в unity. И всё в 2д пространстве. Очень нужна помощь. Ниже на рисунке ожидаемый результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в юнити есть какая-то встроенная вычислительная геометрия? Если нет , то можно попробовать библиотеку Clipper  Angus Johnson или другую, умеющую выполнять операции над полигонами

Comment: Либа это конечно круто, но я бы хотел разобраться в том как это работает. Поэтому ищу алгоритм какой-нибудь, чтобы вникнуть в его работу. Но либу всё равно гляну, спс

Comment: Вам нужно отсечение произвольного полигона прямоугольным окном, точнее, разность полигона и окна. Для выпуклых полигонов это самому реализовать посильно, для не выпуклых намного труднее. Указанная библиотека использует алгоритм Ватти.

Comment: Этот процесс называется отсечением, [polygon clipping](https://www.google.com/search?q=polygon+clipping&rlz=1C1CHZN_ruRU993RU993&sxsrf=ALiCzsaZLh73Dxt4U40z6TvZG6E3_0EkLg:1662736185390&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikvb39_of6AhUrlosKHRGpAxwQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&cshid=1662736344861953&biw=1366&bih=625&dpr=1). Есть тут [Computational-geometry](https://github.com/Habrador/Computational-geometry).